# What determines how many blood shards I get?

Tags: diablo-iii

The boss fights in the Nephalem Rifts often drop multiple blood shards. They show up in bright purple and it says "Blood Shards (X)" where 'x' is the number I received from that fight. It seems like every time I fight one of these rift bosses, I get a different number of blood shards. And, when I play with some of my friends, they usually get a different number than I do. What determines how many blood shards are dropped from Nephalem Rift boss fights?

Comment: I think its RNGeesus but not confirmed yet

Comment: I think difficulty also plays into it. Playing on Norm I usually got 20-30, but when I was leveling up on Torment 1 I often got 50-80.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey I think you're right but it has to be more than that because people in the same game as me, on the same difficulty also get a different number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficulty increases the number of blood shards you get.

The number you get will vary slightly each time. It is a random value within a range determined by your difficult level.